# How do I use nested map statements in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm trying to loop through my data structure. I have nested arrays and I'm trying to use a nested map function in my JSX to get access to it. I'm not getting any errors in my terminal and I'm consoling my object to make sure it's correct and it's returning as expected. The problem is it's not rendering. I think the problem is with my syntax. The second map function doesn't highlight the same way the first one does.

Is this happening because I have two nested if statements? What am I doing wrong?

```
    <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {myForm.controls.map((form, index) => {
        if (form.type === 'text') {
          return (
            <section key={form.prop}>
              <TextInput
                {...form}
                {...errors}
              />
            </section>
          );
        }
        
        if (form.type === 'multi') {
          {form.multiTypes.map(multi => {
            if (multi.type === 'text') {
              return (
                <section key={form.prop}>
                  <TextInput
                    {...form}
                  />
                </section>
              );
            }
          })}
        }
      })}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

// data structure

```
export const FORM: Form = {
  step_1: {
    controls: [
      {
        question: 75, 
        label: 'Primary federal regulator',
        prop: 'question_75',
        style: '',
        type: 'dropdown',
        placeholder: 'Please select one',
        options: [
          {
            label: 'FCC',
            value: 'FCC',
          },
          {
            label: 'FDA',
            value: 'FDA',
          },
        ],
      },
     
      {
        question: 80,
        label: 'Type of Financial Institution',
        prop: 'question_80',
        style: '50%',
        type: 'multi',
        multiTypes: [
          {
            label: '',
            prop: 'question_80',
            style: '50%',
            type: 'text',
          },
          {
            label: '',
            prop: 'question_80',
            style: '50%',
            type: 'dropdown',
          },
        ],

      },


    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're not returning the map statement that wraps your nested map callback:

```js
<form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {myForm.controls.map((form, index) => {
        if (form.type === 'text') {
          return (
            <section key={form.prop}>
              <TextInput
                {...form}
                {...errors}
              />
            </section>
          );
        }
        
        if (form.type === 'multi') {
          // This needs to return something.
          // Looks like you may have been treating this as a JSX child
          // RETURN
          return form.multiTypes.map(multi => {
            if (multi.type === 'text') {
              return (
                <section key={form.prop}>
                  <TextInput
                    {...form}
                  />
                </section>
              );
            }
          })
        }
      })}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: So, here I need to return my map function because I'm in an if statement?

Comment: @London804: You are inside a JavaScript context, not JSX context. In JavaScript `{<expression>}` would be interpreted as a *block*. `<expression>` will be evaluated and its result will be discarded. Within JSX, `{<expression>}` indicates that `<expression>` is JavaScript code and should be evaluated and its result should be used at that position.